# How to install lxml on Nao robot?

Tags: python, lxml, gentoo, nao-robot

I am trying to install lxml on Nao robot using pip. But it gives error:

```
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
```

The OS on the robot doesn't contain gcc or even any package manager. It is based on Linux Gentoo.

I created a VM of the OS(http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/dev/tools/opennao.html) and installed the required packages: libxml2 and libxslt. It already had .so files for both in /usr/lib. Then I copied the header files to the /usr/include directory on the robot. But it still throws error.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you install your .so and Python file locally, next to where your program will be run, instead.

Otherwise, you can take the Gentoo package you compiled in your VM, and untar it at the root of NAO's filesystem, and you'll have it installed on your NAO. But that does not work on a Pepper, which root access has been disabled.